# samsung netbook OS for clean install

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, netbook

I recently had a problem with a corrupted registry on a samsung N120.  When all else failed i reformatted the drive.

However having bought the machine with windows home ed pre-installed, I didn't have original windows disck for the clean install. So I managed to install another edition of windows XP (PRO this time).

Now windows opens, but several key functions are missing. e.g.:

- screen resolution - will not allow me  any but 800x600 resolution
- native   buttons - such as the fn + screen    brightness is not working at all.

Any suggestions please?

? Is there a way to  get the samsung OS online (since I do   have the manufacturer's/installed  product key)?

thanks

PS: It has been my intention to install ubuntu, but i need to know i will not lose functions like screen brightness, volume, and the trackpad's scrolling function.  I'd be happy to bypass the windows option if i was sure to have full keyboard/samsung functionality

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows**: You have to install the drivers from your manufacturer. Video driver for example and the pack for Fn buttons. There are helpers for that usually from the manufacturer. [Here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_ia_cd=05013600&prd_mdl_cd=&prd_mdl_name=NP-N120&prd_ia_sub_class_cd=P) is the official page for it.

**Ubuntu**: The brightness will work. Volume will work. (These are pure ACPI functions, usually they 'just work'.) Trackpad scrolling works. (Comese with xf86-input-synaptics driver, it works usually Out-of-the-box.) That's all. But don't expect ALL the features to work and you will have lower battery capability (since Linux just can't use all the ACPI functions due to manufacturer..). Also, suspend and hibernation is a works or not. You have to try it out. Install Ubuntu INTO XP (use "Wubi" installer) and try these out. If they work, decide what you want to use. I'd go with XP if you use battery a lot. If not, you can take Ubuntu (also Ubuntu will eat your PC more, it consumes more resource.. (nah I'm not a Win fan or whatever, but it makes sense. XP is a ~7year old OS, Ubuntu is a few weeks old.. so to say. :))

If Ubuntu fails, you can try Fedora 13. It'll come 9 days later and will bring fresh stuff, it'll be more likely to run where Ubuntu failed (since Ubuntu ships a bit older stuff now due to the Long-term-support release.) And if someone fails, you know where to come for help. ;P

Side note: If you try it with live cd, there is a chance it will work or not. Upgrades on Ubuntu (not just  Ubuntu but we're talking about that at the minute) can break things. So after the first bunch of fixes it may work or not. That's why you should install it and try it out in Wubi.

Comment: many thanks - solution worked fine, and the Ubuntu comments are most useful and thought provoking.

I want ubuntu cos I am in principle committed to the open source idea, though usually locked into the microsoft world ... Iwill try the virtual route, and advance with caution after that.

many thanks,

a

Answer (score 0):

First try Ubuntu from Live USB. If it's ok for you then install it. I use it everyday in work and home and it fits my needs perfectly.